# RSpec in simple class with an error: please stub a default value first

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to test simple class which iterate through array of hashes and return only those with status `Pending` which were updated more than 2 days ago.

`fetch_pending.rb`

```
  class FetchPending
    PROJECT_KEY = 'TPFJT'
    TWO_DAYS = Time.now - 2 * 24 * 60 * 60

    def call
      project.select do |issue|
        issue.fields.dig('status', 'name') == 'Pending' &&
          DateTime.parse(issue.fields.dig('updated')) < TWO_DAYS
      end
    end

    private

    def project
      @project ||= Jira::ProjectConnection.new(PROJECT_KEY).call
    end
  end
```

`specs`

```
RSpec.describe FetchPending do
  subject { described_class.new }

  let(:project_key) { 'TSW-123' }
  let(:project_hash) do
    [
      {
        'key': 'TP-47',
        'fields': {
          'status': {
            'name': 'Pending'
          },
          'assignee': {
            'name': 'michael.kelso',
            'emailAddress': 'michael.kelso@example.com'
          },
          'updated': '2020-02-19T13:20:50.539+0100'
        }
      }
    ]
  end
  let(:project) { instance_double(Jira::ProjectConnection) }

  before do
    allow(Jira::ProjectConnection).to receive(:new).with('TSW-123').and_return(project)
    allow(project).to receive(:call).and_return(project_hash)
  end

  it 'return project hash' do
    expect(subject.call).include(key[:'TP-47'])
  end
```

But I've got an error:

```
Failure/Error: expect(subject.call).include(key[:'TP-47'])

   #<Jira::ProjectConnection (class)> received :new with unexpected arguments
     expected: ("TSW-123")
          got: ("TPFJT")
    Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well.
```

I've got the same issue in few other specs, how to stub this variable? should I do the same ith `TWO_DAYS` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual code is passing `FetchPending::ProjectKey` as the argument to `Jira::ProjectConnection.new`.

In your test you are defining a variable:

```
let(:project_key) { 'TSW-123' }
```

but this isn't actually getting used anywhere.

A simple fix would be to change

```
allow(Jira::ProjectConnection).to receive(:new).with('TSW-123').and_return(project)
```

with

```
allow(Jira::ProjectConnection).to receive(:new).with(described_class::PROJECT_KEY).and_return(project)
```